# Solr Distinct on multi-valued field

Tags: solr, lucene

I have Solr documents with a multi-valued field, and need the distinct values from it.  I have to filter by a different field, but my result doesn't have to incklude anything other than the distinct categories.

Documents:

```
{CountryCode: 'US', Product:'A', Categories:[1,2,3]},
{CountryCode: 'US', Product:'B', Categories:[1,3,77,88]},
{CountryCode: 'JP', Product:'B', Categories:[1,2]}
{CountryCode: 'JP', Product:'B', Categories:[444,555]}
```

Filter for only  CountryCode = 'US'

Result:

```
{[1,2,3,77,88]}
```

I tried field collapsing/grouping, but it doesn't work on multi-valued fields.

I tried terms(thanks to suggestion by Persimmonium), but it doesn't want to filter only the 'US' categories.  The fact that terms gave how many times a category occurs is a bonus, but not required in this case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after your comment.

One way to achieve this is with:

- a fq to get the set of docs you are interested in
- then facet on Categories, setting 'limit' high enough to get all values

A fancier way might be using[Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions). But faceting is just simpler.

Comment: Thanks.  Played around with it.  I tried to filter the documents by another field first, but it doesn't look like that is supported.  e.g. each document also has a countryCode, and I only want something from one of those

Comment: so, you want to: 1. get some docs with a fq 2. then get all unique values of a field only in docs returned, correct? that is a different story...will think when i have some time

Comment: correct - i will add more details to my original post

Comment: Faceting should work, yes. You can use limit=-1 to get all facet terms.

Comment: @MatsLindh - thanks! That gets me some data to work with!